# QR code not working for big data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using https://github.com/monospaced/angular-qrcode library to generate qr code in my page. I came a cross a problem when I need to specify data which is 2700 characters long string. I shortened the string until I could see the qr code which is 271 characters. I am able to display those using version 10. If I add another character, qr code is not showing despite increasing version. I am using this demo page http://monospaced.github.io/angular-qrcode/
For Data there is 271 characters long string, version = 10, error correction - low. Is the library broken or I have misunderstood something? Looking at http://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html I understand that I should be able to provide string that is up to 2,953 characters long using version 40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, the library you use only allows qr code versions up to 10. At least they state that on the link you provieded:

https://github.com/monospaced/angular-qrcode

> ## Options
>
> Permitted values
>
> version: 1-10

271 is the exact max binary size for version 10 size.

Comment: Sorry for missing such detail. Funny though that in demo they don't limit it to version 10.